# How to block multiple signup with different mobile number?

Tags: android

I'm developing an android app which contains registration form also,

Here I want to make user can register only once in the device. and if register again (by clearing data or reinstall) with different mobile number and email id, app should give error message.

Comment: May I know what you tried so far?

Comment: @androidOnHigh i tried by taking android device Id... it works fine... but if we ask permission for device identity user may uninstall our app (On security concern), so is there any approach to achieve this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alone cannot be achieved on mobile device itself. You also need to maintain server which keep the identity of `device` and user `mobile number` together. device identity can be **`combination of IMEI and device id`**

1. When you try to register, you do all local validation on client but ultimately 1 network call is must to register, for this send `device_id` and newly registered number.
2. Next time when some user tries to register with new number from same device, u'd already have this information on server, server can respond back telling, hey looks like this mobile device is already associated with an number do you wish to use the previous number instead.
3. In case, user denies, he must be allowed to delete the old relation between oldnumber-current device.
4. There after he can proceed with the way initially he started to register.
5. Also this is completely business requirement, whether u want to have 1device-> #numbers or #numbers -> 1device. But i would rather suggest to keep it safe simple and secure with 1device->1number.

Comment: i know this...  but if we ask permission for device identity user may uninstall our app (On security concern), so is there any approach to achieve this...

Comment: No it is not required.

Comment: yeah, but in play store it will show app needs access to Device Id, at that time user may feel security concerns

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to check IMEI number of device

IMEI number will not be changed if sim card changed.

Comment: i know this...  but if we ask permission for device identity user may uninstall our app (On security concern), so is there any approach to achieve this...

Comment: yes it will be possible, but you can give instruction to user that you need to this permission for (your IMIE purpose), you will not any other use of this permission.

Answer (score 2):

> For Android Version 6 And Above, WLAN MAC Address has been [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-hardware-id).

For uniquely Identification of devices, You can Use [Secure.ANDROID_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID).
And we don't need any additional permission to retrieve Android ID.

you can get Android Id like:

```
public String getDeviceUniqueID(Activity activity){
    String device_unique_id = Secure.getString(activity.getContentResolver(),
            Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    return device_unique_id;
}
```

Comment: I have heard this id can change when a user resets (Factory reset) their phone. Is it reliable?

Comment: You have heard right. This is the valid case as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by below approach.

On sign up, get user device **IMEI** number as well and store on server database as well.(In this step make sure that user that **IMEI** number does not exist)

Comment: i know this...  but if we ask permission for device identity user may uninstall our app (On security concern), so is there any approach to achieve this...